# A 13"x19" printer / archival quality ink combination?

Tags: printing, printer, ink-jet, archival

I've been looking at the Canon® PIXMA PRO-100 which has positive reviews but it uses Canon ChromaLife100 ink which is rated for 100 years when stored in an album.  Can this be considered "archival" quality?  What is a good 13"x19" that uses archival quality ink. I am planning to print on cotton, acid-free, photo rag art media.

Comment: If serious people are offering > 100 years I'd be interested in links. I'm by no means suggesting that they don't exist - just that it's hard to guaranteed any chemical process with any sort of certainty at that sort of time span. | FWIW standard silver process black & white prints that 100 years old are often in good condition.

Comment: Common wisdom is that pigment-based inks are more fade resistant then dye inks (400 years is claimed in [an Epson press release](http://www.wilhelm-research.com/epson_uchd_nr/epson_uchd_nr.html)). So, the Pro-1 or Pro-10 may be more what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epson P600 is getting very good reviews. I have a P800 which uses the same inks (in larger more cost effective cartridges, which was my reason for selecting the P800 over the P600 almost as much as print size) and I can attest to excellent color saturation and black levels which will surely produce satisfactory results.

Archival stability for the Epson UltrChromeHD inks these printers use is claimed, though of course I cannot speak to personal experience on that having gotten the printer a month ago :)